# TeslaDecryptがvisual studio2019でコンパイルできない

Tags: visual-studio, openssl

GitHubで公開されている [TeslaDecrypt](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/TeslaDecrypt) のコードがコンパイルできなくて困っています。
環境は、windows10(64bit),Visual Studio2019(64bit)を用いています。
ビルドは以下の手順でおこないました。

1. 「コードの複製またはチェックアウトする」から[こちら](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/TeslaDecrypt)のリポジトリをコピー
2. 「TeslaDecrypter_vs2015.sln」を読み込む
3. ソリューションのビルドをおこなう

その結果エラーとしては以下のものが出力されます。

```
重大度レベル  コード 説明  プロジェクト  ファイル    行   抑制状態
エラー (アクティブ) E1696   ソース ファイルを開けません "openssl\\ec_lcl.h"  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 33  
エラー (アクティブ) E1696   ソース ファイルを開けません "openssl\\ech_locl.h"    TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 34  
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 918 
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 921 
エラー (アクティブ) E0020   識別子 "ECDH_DATA" が定義されていません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 940 
エラー (アクティブ) E0020   識別子 "ecdh_data" が定義されていません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 940 
エラー (アクティブ) E0020   識別子 "ecdh_check" が定義されていません TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 961 
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 1032    
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 1034    
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 1043    
エラー (アクティブ) E0393   不完全クラス型へのポインターは使用できません  TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 1095    
エラー C1083    include ファイルを開けません。'openssl\\ec_lcl.h':No such file or directory   TeslaDecrypter  D:\Source\Repos\TeslaDecrypt\AlphaCrypt.cpp 33
```

どうやらopensslのcrypto library？のヘッダーファイルがincludeできないことに起因しているように見受けられます。

一応以下のopensslのincludeは正常におこなわれているのでなおさら困っています。

```
#include "openssl\\ecdh.h"
#include "openssl\\aes.h"           
#include "openssl\\sha.h"
```

opensslを導入する際は、vcpkgで次のコマンドでおこないました。

```
vcpkg install openssl-windows
```

その結果以下のようなフォルダ構造となり、crypto libraryが導入できていないようです。

```
tree C:\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows
フォルダー パスの一覧
ボリューム シリアル番号は xxxxxxxxx です
C:\VCPKG-MASTER\INSTALLED\X64-WINDOWS
├─bin
├─debug
│  ├─bin
│  └─lib
├─include
│  └─openssl
├─lib
├─share
│  ├─openssl
│  └─openssl-windows
└─tools
    └─openssl
```

どなたかcrypto libraryの導入方法もしくは解決方法のご教授をお願いします。